# Bing News API Error 403 - InsufficientAuthorization

Tags: angularjs, api, http, http-status-code-403, bing-api

I've been trying to work on a project with angularJS and the bing search api's v7. However, whenever I make a http request to the provided URL ("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news?") I get an error 403 response with error message: "Insufficient Authorization". I looked at the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/includes/bing-error-codes-v7) and they said the error could be caused "if the subscription key has been disabled or has expired."

However, I just got this key today. It seems odd that it would have expired or already been deactivated. Not sure what could be going on here.

Relevant code is

```
    var params = {
        // Bing news search request parameters
        "q": "query",
        "count": "3",
        "offset": "0",
        "mkt": "en-us",
        "safesearch": "Moderate"
    };
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news?"+ $httpParamSerializer(params),
        headers:{"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key":"my_subscription key"}
    }).then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(response);

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(response);
        });
```

What could be causing this issue? If it's a problem with the API, are there any other good news-gathering API's available?

Comment: As a followup, I don't have an azure account, I just signed up for the trial and they gave me a pair of keys to access the websites. Do I need an azure account to access the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news" giving 403
>   - InsufficientAuthorization?

The v5.0 url works. The v7.0 simply won't. This seems to be Microsoft.
After all it is still in preview.

On either v5.0 or 7.0 **/search** works.
And for **/trendingtopics** you need to pass *?mkt=* with *en-US* or *zh-CN*.

> Do I need an azure account to access the API?

No, you do not need an Azure account. The API keys generated can be used in the [API test from Microsoft](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f72cf5ff8098cef380a/operations/56f02400dbe2d91900c68553)(if available), in Postman or any other mechanism that makes the request for you.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using the search. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news is a different end-point. It is meant for category news search: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/e5e22123c5d24f1081f63af1548defa1/operations/56f02400dbe2d91900c68553.

The https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news/search defined here: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/e5e22123c5d24f1081f63af1548defa1/operations/56b449fbcf5ff81038d15cdf is the correct end-point for getting news for a given query.

Both the endpoints work for their respective usecases - the one without "/search" for category news (optional "category" parameter) and one with "/search" for the intended usecase here.